# TensorflowJS - React Native - Error predicting from tensor image

Tags: react-native, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter, expo-camera

I'm trying to get a keras model I converted to tensorflowJS to work in react native but getting the error in predicting the image tensor.

I have trained a custom tensorflow keras model and converted the keras h5 model to JavaScript JSON model. In React Native project, I have used expo camera with tensorflow to capture the image to predict the damage on the captured image.

Here, I have included the versions use in my projects, commands used to convert and predict the model.

**Versions used**

- React Native Project
  "expo": ">=45.0.0-0 <46.0.0",
  "expo-camera": "~12.2.0",
  "expo-gl": "~11.3.0",
  "expo-gl-cpp": "~11.3.0",
  "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.0.0",
  "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
  "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
- Python

  "tensorflow Version" : 2.10.0

Command used to convert Keras h5 to JS json :

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras --weight_shard_size_bytes=419430400 --quantize_float16=* /path/to/model.h5 /path/to/output
```

Creating and using Layers model in RN

```
 // Load layers model using model json and weights file
 const models = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, weights));
```

Logs of Capturing Image via expo camera and cameraWithTensors

```
 LOG  imageAsTensors:  {"kept":false,"isDisposedInternal":false,"shape":[224,224,3],"dtype":"int32","size":150528,"strides":[672,3],"dataId":{"id":670},"id":980,"rankType":"3"}
 LOG  imageTensorReshaped:  {"kept":false,"isDisposedInternal":false,"shape":[1,224,224,3],"dtype":"int32","size":150528,"strides":[150528,672,3],"dataId":{"id":670},"id":981,"rankType":"4","scopeId":408}
```

Predicting image tensor using model

```
try {
      // predict against the model
      const output = await models.predict(imageTensorReshaped, { batchSize: 1 });
      return output.dataSync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error predicting from tensor image', error);
    }
```

Receiving the below error in catch
Error predicting from tensor image [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'opHandler.clone')]

Expectations : Prediction result array

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the setOpHandler function is not being called in the tfjs-node files in the package.
You can check out this issue on github [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/7041)! for a temporary fix using the provided patch files